# How to trim fields when loading into dataframe in spark?

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, data-ingestion

We recently received a file to be ingested, the file is PSV format, however, all the fields are padded with extra characters $~$ on the left and right, so the entire PSV is like below:

> $~$Field1$~$|$~$Field2$~$|$~$Field3$~$
>
> $~$Data1$~$|$~$Data2$~$|$~$Data3$~$
>
> $~$Data4$~$|$~$Data5$~$|$~$Data6$~$
>
> $~$Data7$~$|$~$Data8$~$|$~$Data9$~$
>
> $~$Data10$~$|$~$Data11$~$|$~$Data12$~$ .....

There are 100 Million rows in the file.

What would be the best way to trim these paddings so as to make it a standard PSV?

Thank you very much, any suggestion/sharing is appreciated here.

UPDATE:

The data is received from SFTP, and uploaded to Hadoop by IT Data Support (Unix Admin), we only have access to Hadoop cluster, but if it is an easy job for Data Support, maybe I can convince them to do the preprocess. Thanks.

Comment: seems trivial if you were to use a through stream or unix pipe as a preprocessor.  is that an option?

Comment: oh? I am not unix person, can you shed with more light? Thank you very much. keep in mind the volume of the data. OP updated.

Comment: yeah, streams are generally the best way to do something like this because they can do processing on smaller buffer or line by line.  essentially on unix you have tool like cat and sed and you can pipe one into another eg cat file.csv | sed('regex').  i'm not a sed or awk expert but you can likely use them in place without cat or piping too.

Comment: Thank you, please post it as an answer, I will accept it once I see it. The sed costs me nearly an hour to trim off the extra characters off from the 28GB data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tr` might be the faster solution.  note, you can pipe any strings, so in this case, I'm `cat`ing a file on disk, but this can also be a file stream from sftp.

```sh
~/Desktop/test $ cat data.txt
$~$Field1$~$|$~$Field2$~$|$~$Field3$~$

$~$Data1$~$|$~$Data2$~$|$~$Data3$~$

$~$Data4$~$|$~$Data5$~$|$~$Data6$~$

$~$Data7$~$|$~$Data8$~$|$~$Data9$~$

# the '>' will open a new file for writing

~/Desktop/test $ cat data.txt | tr -d \$~\$ > output.psv

# see the results here
~/Desktop/test $ cat output.psv 
Field1|Field2|Field3

Data1|Data2|Data3

Data4|Data5|Data6

Data7|Data8|Data9
```

examples: https://shapeshed.com/unix-tr/#what-is-the-tr-command-in-unix

Comment: would cat work for such a big file? sed -ie 's/\$\~\$//g' filename is what I used. Thanks

Comment: i don't think cat has any file size limitations, it should stream the bytes from the top of the file on down.  there may be implementation where you would hit max file descriptors if you piped your output into file vs. single file descriptor open eg `>`.i think this tr stream will outperform sed in place too. but sed should be reasonably fast depending on your hardware. good luck! https://serverfault.com/questions/429352/file-size-limit-exceeded-in-bash/429369#429369:

Comment: Thank you for your kind enlightening.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure Spark solution. There might be better performing solutions.

```
var df = spark.read.option("delimiter", "|").csv(filePath)
val replace = (value: String, find: String, replace: String) => value.replace(find, replace)
val replaceUdf = udf(replace)
df.select(
       df.columns.map(c => replaceUdf(col(c), lit("$~$"), lit("")).alias(c)): _*)
  .show
```

Update: You cannot use `$~$` as `quote` option or use `$~$|$~$` as a `delimiter` in the 2.3.0 as those options accept only single character.

Comment: Agree, But instead of " | " you can use "$~$|$~$" as delimitter, so we dont have to run udf on too many columns

Comment: You cannot. Delimiter must be one character. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using regexp_replace and foldLeft to update all columns. Check this out

```
scala> val df = Seq(("$~$Data1$~$","$~$Data2$~$","$~$Data3$~$"), ("$~$Data4$~$","$~$Data5$~$","$~$Data6$~$"), ("$~$Data7$~$","$~$Data8$~$","$~$Data9$~$"),("$~$Data10$~$","$~$Data11$~$","$~$Data12$~$")).toDF("Field1","field2","field3")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Field1: string, field2: string ... 1 more field]

scala> df.show(false)
+------------+------------+------------+
|Field1      |field2      |field3      |
+------------+------------+------------+
|$~$Data1$~$ |$~$Data2$~$ |$~$Data3$~$ |
|$~$Data4$~$ |$~$Data5$~$ |$~$Data6$~$ |
|$~$Data7$~$ |$~$Data8$~$ |$~$Data9$~$ |
|$~$Data10$~$|$~$Data11$~$|$~$Data12$~$|
+------------+------------+------------+


scala> val df2 = df.columns.foldLeft(df) { (acc,x) => acc.withColumn(x,regexp_replace(col(x),"""^\$~\$|\$~\$$""","")) }
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Field1: string, field2: string ... 1 more field]

scala> df2.show(false)
+------+------+------+
|Field1|field2|field3|
+------+------+------+
|Data1 |Data2 |Data3 |
|Data4 |Data5 |Data6 |
|Data7 |Data8 |Data9 |
|Data10|Data11|Data12|
+------+------+------+


scala>
```